# In Rails, what exactly is form_for? It seems magical

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First of all, I realize I should have tried to fully grasp Ruby before jumping into Rails. However, nothing in Ruby seemed too difficult to quickly grasp (until this!), so I decided to get started while I was still enthusiastic about learning. ,__,

Anyway, here is a super-condensed example of `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I understand that methods in Ruby need not be called with parenthesis. However, `form_for` *is* being called with parenthesis, and yet somehow, it seems as though the `do |f|` block is being passed to it!

Is `form_for` returning a method that takes a block, and then is *that* method immediately being called (without parenthesis) by passing the `do |f|` block? What's going on here?

Comment: Nothing is Voodoo in rails. Wipe you spectacles and you'll see that its all just ruby!

Comment: maybe it would be helpful to look at the source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb to see that the final parameter is a &proc and is required: 
  `def form_for(record, options = {}, &proc)raise ArgumentError, "Missing block" unless block_given?`

Comment: Everyone gave awesome answers! Thank you, and +1 for all.


And thanks Jed! I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby uses a lot of what is called 'syntactic sugar' in that it is a bit more flexible than other languages in how certain operations are interpreted.

for instance:

```
model.property = "something"
```

is actually a function call:

```
model.property=("something")
```

your `form_for` example is a similar case. Blocks are silently passed into Ruby functions as a parameter.

```
my_block = Proc.new { some code }
my_function(param1, param2, &my_block)
```

is equivalent to

```
my_function param1, param2 do
  some code
end
```

and in the function def for `my_function` you could write:

```
def my_function(param1, param2, &block)
```

and you could access the block via the parameter, as well as `yield`.

So when you use block syntax, it's interpreted as a parameter, but it's really not.

Comment: I think this may answer the question I left on Pär Wieslander's answer.

In Ruby, is the "sugary/magical" passing of blocks as a parameter something that is unique to blocks? 

In other words, you couldn't do the same with a variable -- correct?

Comment: Wow, I asked that confusingly.

Comment: @Closure Cowboy passing a block into a function outside of the comma-delimited list of parameters is a special case, yes.

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is simply that the `form_for` method is invoked with both parameters and a block in the same call.

Here's a basic example of a method taking both a parameter and a block, to illustrate the principle:

```
def hello(name)
  puts "Hello, #{name}!"
  yield if block_given?
  puts "Goodbye, #{name}!"
end
```

This method can be called with a single parameter, or with a parameter and a block:

```
> hello("John")
Hello, John!
Goodbye, John!

> hello("John") do
*   puts "Inside the block"
* end
Hello, John!
Inside the block
Goodbye, John!
```

Regarding the question in your comment:

> Why are there parenthesis around only the first parameter? After encountering the open+closed parenthesis after form_for, how does Ruby know that it should "wait" before calling the method?

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking why there's only parentheses around `@post` in the `form_for` call, and not around the entire block. That's the syntax for passing a block to a method in Ruby - if a block follows immediately after the method and its regular parameters, the block is passed along to the method together with the parameters.

Here are a few of the most common ways of calling a method in Ruby:

```
# Calling a method without a block
mymethod(param1, param2)

# Same as above, but leaving out parentheses
mymethod param1, param2

# Calling a method with a block that takes no arguments
# (this works without parentheses too)
mymethod(param1, param2) { do_stuff_in_block() }

# or
# (this works without parentheses too)
mymethod(param1, param2) do
  do_stuff_in_block()
end

# Calling a method with a block that takes arguments
# (this works without parentheses too)
mymethod(param1, param2) do |arg1, arg2|
  do_stuff_in_block(arg1, arg2)
end

# or
# (this works without parentheses too)
mymethod(param1, param2) { |arg1, arg2| do_stuff_in_block(arg1, arg2) }
```

Have a look at [Blocks and Iterators in Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html#S2) for more details about both how to call methods with blocks and how to write your own methods that accept blocks.

Comment: Why are there parenthesis around only the first parameter? After encountering the open+closed parenthesis after `form_for`, how does Ruby know that it should "wait" before calling the method? If that question seems insane, please let me know...

Comment: parens just evaluate first, consider
  `form_for (@post ||= Post.new) {|f| block stuff }`
will use the @post var if available or create a new one and assign it to @post.

Comment: @Closure Cowboy: I added some more examples and a link to the Programming Ruby book online, which explains blocks quite nicely. Hopefully this makes things more clear.

Comment: Pär Wieslander, thank you for taking the time to update your answer. If I could vote you up again, I could! That explains things very, very nicely. I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 separate questions, but I will answer the more pressing one first:

```
form_for @product do |f|
  # stuff here
end
```

and

```
form_for(@product) do |f|
  # stuff here
end
```

Are exactly the same thing. `form_for` is a method that takes `block` as a parameter, amongst other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Methods in ruby can be passed arguments (e.g. `@post`) and a block (e.g. all the stuff inside the `do` ... `end`).

If you look at how [`form_for` is defined within rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L301) you will see:

```
def form_for(record, options = {}, &proc)
  # a lot of funky magical rails stuff ...
end
```

Everything in the `do` block is captured in `proc`. The preceding `&` in the method definition indicates that `proc` is a block and can be executed. Somewhere along the line, rails will execute `proc`.

Blocks are a big part of ruby's magical awesomeness. Check [this awesome free ruby e-book](http://www.humblelittlerubybook.com/book/html/chapter2.html) for more info on blocks. Blocks are a kind of 'closure' and ruby has different flavors of closures which behave slightly differently (the other common closure is `lambda`). If you want to dig real deep into how closures work in Ruby, check out [this great tutorial](http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby.rb).